# Can I use now with present simple?

Tags: grammar

For example I have sentence:

> Thanks for your help. Now I don't see any errors in ........

I've been taught that with now I should use present continuous, but in this case it seems ok for me to use present simple.

Comment: Now, I like apples. Before now, I  hated them. You were taught incorrectly.

Comment: "I've been taught that with now I should use present continuous" - if you hear a rule regarding English, you can bet that there will be plenty of exceptions to that rule. There are very few (none that I can think of) rules of any kind in English that do not get broken every so often, or a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> Thanks for your help. Now I don't see any errors in...

is correct, and "*now*" may be used with the *simple present*.

Perhaps the **rule** you were taught was

> Now + *be* + *verb-ing*
>
> Now, I *am* not *seeing* any errors.
>   Now, she *is going* home.
>   The children *are now sleeping*.